# How to change JsonView for specific properties

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, json-view

Hi I have few UI objects that embedded into each other. Example #1:

```
class CarUI {
  public UserUI user;
  public UserUI agent;
  ....
  public UserUI getUser() {
    return user;
  }
  public UserUI getAgent() {
    return agent;
  }
}
class UserUI {
  @JsonView({Views.Public.class,Views.Private.class})
  public String name;
  @JsonView({Views.Private.class})
  public String phone;
  ...
}
```

As you can see if I serialize UserUI as Public I will expose only name but for private I will expose all fields.

Here is my question: when I serialize object CarUI I want to expose only name for "user" and both name+phone for "agent". That essentially means that in the getter for the getUser() I want to change JsonView to Views.Public.class and for getAgent() I want to change it to Views.Private.class

Is there way to overwrite JsonView in getters to make all hierarchy for the returned object now serialize using this new JsonView?

**Edited**
As pointed below you can solve my Example#1 with JsonView inheritance. What about more generic. Here is Example#2:

```
class CarUI {
  public UserUI user;
  public UserUI agent;
  ....
  public UserUI getUser() {
    return user;
  }
  public UserUI getAgent() {
    return agent;
  }
}
class UserUI {
  @JsonView({Views.Public.class,Views.Private.class})
  public String name;
  @JsonView({Views.Private.class})
  public String phone;
  @JsonView({Views.Public.class})
  public String avatarUrl;
  ...
}
```

In this example Id like to display name+phone for Agent and name+avatarUrl for User.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JsonView accepts inheritance. Views.Private fields extends Views.Public fields. This means Views.Private serialization will also look for the Views.Public annotations.

```
public Views {
    public Public {}
    public Private extends Public {}
}

class CarUI {
  public UserUI user;
  public UserUI agent;
  ....
  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  public UserUI getUser() {
    return user;
  }
  @JsonView(Views.Private.class)
  public UserUI getAgent() {
    return agent;
  }
}

class UserUI {
  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  public String name;
  @JsonView(Views.Private.class)
  public String phone;
  ...
}
```

For Example #2

You can introduce multiple classes like:

```
public Views {
    public Public {}
    public Private1 extends Public {}
    public Private2 extends Public {}
}

class CarUI {
  public UserUI user;
  public UserUI agent;
  ....
  public UserUI getUser() {
    return user;
  }
  public UserUI getAgent() {
    return agent;
  }
}
class UserUI {
  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  public String name;
  @JsonView({Views.Private1.class})
  public String phone;
  @JsonView({Views.Private2.class})
  public String avatarUrl;
  ...
}
```

Or you can use view-less properties and use no inheritance:

```
public Views {
    public Public {}
    public Private {}
}

class CarUI {
  public UserUI user;
  public UserUI agent;
  ....
  public UserUI getUser() {
    return user;
  }
  public UserUI getAgent() {
    return agent;
  }
}
class UserUI {
  // This one is view-less shows every time unless you specificy
  public String name;
  @JsonView({Views.Private.class})
  public String phone;
  @JsonView({Views.Public.class})
  public String avatarUrl;
  ...
}

...
// If you want to hide view-less properties, default is true 
objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false); 
...
```

Comment: Thank you. That will work for my example where 2 JsonViews overlap on properties. What if Public has property that Private does not have and opposite. See above Example #2.

Comment: Edited my answer. Tried to use multiple classes in @JsonView annotation however no luck in there.

Answer (score 1):

Just found more generic case if anyone need. Basically you can transform your property inside getter using different JsonView as such:

```
  @JsonView({ Views.Detail.class})
  public JsonNode getAgent() throws IOException {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      String json = mapper.writerWithView(Views.Private.class).writeValueAsString(agent);
      return mapper.readTree(json);
  }
```